# PHP5.5 MySQL inside a CLASS trouble declaring the variable for connection

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo, global-variables

Hello I am trying to use connection to validate and eventually register users into my DB. I have created a class called `Registration` where I have my validation methods and so on. However I have problem with my PDO connection / declaring this variable. Here is some code:

**Start**

```
<?php
require 'includes/crypt/lib/password.php';
require 'includes/db_connect.php';
require 'includes/authentication_generator.php';
```

**Current Code : NOT WORKING**

```
$pdo = connect();
class Registration{
    //Variables used
    public $errors = array();
    public $pdo;

    public function __construct(){
        $pdo = connect();
    }
```

**Other ways I have attempted**

```
class Registration{
//Variables used
public $errors = array();
$pdo = connect();
```

This code gives me error it says `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$pdo' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp\htdocs\rdr_dev\includes\registration.php on line 9`

**Second attempt**

```
class Registration{
//Variables used
public $errors = array();
public $pdo = connect();
```

This gives me error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\rdr_dev\includes\registration.php on line 9`

I am sort of running out of the ideas, I am wondering also is there a better way to use this connection as I tried to declare it on every page I was going to use it and it told me that it could not be declared more than one time. What is the current standard on how to use this?

Thanks

Comment: when using class..you need to access variable as `$this->pdo`

Comment: You need to learn basic OOP syntax in PHP. You cannot have "executable code" outside of a method in a class. Your `... = connect()` would have to be done in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

got it figured out with little help from Google and Murach's book

**code**

require 'includes/db_connect.php';

```
class Registration{
    //Variables used
    public $errors = array();
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(){
        $con = new Connection();
        $this->pdo = $con->getConnection();
    }
```

**re-created DB connection into a class**

```
class Connection{

    protected $db;

    public function Connection(){

    $conn = NULL;

        try{
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=RDR_Dev", "", "");
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch(PDOException $e){
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
                }    
            $this->db = $conn;
    }

    public function getConnection(){
        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping everyone!